# Curl SSL Request 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https, openssl

I'm trying to make a request using php and curl. Heres a working example that I use from command line

```
curl -k --cacert c:/cert/server_ca.pem  --cert c:/cert/signed_client_cert.pem --key c:/cert/cert_req_rsa_private_key.pem
```

heres what I have so far, It returns a 400- bad request, does anyone know how I can get more usefull errors or what I could be doing wrong?

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//phpinfo();

$cert = "C:/cert/signed_client_cert.pem";
$key = "C:/cert/cert_req_rsa_private_key.pem";
$pass = "key1123";
$caInfo = "C:/cert/server_ca.pem";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.apitest.com/v/2/products/04003274058");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caInfo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pass);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $pass);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM');


$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
echo var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely the issue seems to be a bug in Php's curl, I switched to httprequest and it worked

Answer (score 2):

The `curl` command is incomplete, so its hard to say what may (or may not) be different. But from the command line, Curl uses `Accept: */*`; and does not use `Content-Type` (see the Wireshark capture below for `curl www.google.com`)).

For reading on the difference between `Accept` and `Content-Type`, see [Difference between accept and content-type http headers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-accept-and-content-type-http-headers) on Webmasters Stack Exchange.

[image]

---

Just bike shedding, but this has room for improvement:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

If you feel you have to use it like that, then pick an anonymous protocol. It will save the server from sending its certificate since nothing is being verified anyway.